# How do I only pay the cost of a function's created return value, when that return value is actually used?

Tags: c++, function, optimization, c++11, return-value

Often times I see transformer functions that will take a parameter by reference, and also return that same parameter as a function's return value.

For example:

```
std::string& Lowercase(std::string & str){
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
    return str;
}
```

I understand that this is done as a convenience, and I am under the impression that the compiler will optimize for cases when the return value is not actually used.  However, I don't believe the compiler can optimize for newly created return values of non-basic types.  For example:

```
std::tuple<int,std::string,float> function(int const& num, std::string const& str, float const& f){

    return std::tuple<int,std::string,float>(num,str,f);
}
```

Constructors could do almost anything, and although the return type isn't used, it does not mean it would be safe to avoid creating the type.  However, in this case, it would be advantageous to not create the type when the return value of the function isn't used.

Is there some kind of way to notify the compiler that if the return type is not being used, it's safe to avoid the creation of the type?  This would be function specific, and a decision of the programmers; not something that the compiler could figure out on its own.

Comment: I would say that optimization may remove a lot. You may have to allow optimization between translation unit for no-inline function.

Comment: It seems to me that better program design would be preferable. Can you give a concrete example of where/why this would be a necessary feature?

Comment: try casting the functions return to a (void), I used to see that being done to make certain warning messages go away (the ignored return value messages, especially on things like printf - where you often really didnt care about hte return value.)

Comment: There is nothing to optimize in the first case: the function is returning a reference.

Comment: Also, the standard does allow for bypassing some constructors in some circumstances, irrespective of those ctr function having interesting content/side-effect. I would not be surprised if inline code saw these optimizations occur.

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield Just playing with the language.  I suppose you could argue that if the function is creating something, and that something does not have to be used, then the function is in turn, doing two things- which may be considered bad program design.  I'm not too familiar with how functional languages work, but perhaps it would be convenient to return the parameter list in a fashion I've shown with the tuple.  Again, not a concrete example of a necessary feature, but perhaps something of a convenience.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett I ran the tuple-returning function above compared to an identical function that returned void instead.  with GCC(4.8.2) -Ofast, both inlined, they did not run at the same speed.  This is what prompted me to ask.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `function` and if the function is not inlined it [might not optimize it since it has non trivial constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272964/will-the-c-compiler-optimize-away-unused-return-value). However, if the function is inlined it might optimize the unused return class if it's lifetime affects none of the arguments. Also since tuple is a standard type i believe most compiler will optimize that returned variable.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are two ways the compiler optimize your code:

1. (Named) Return value optimization (RVO/NRVO)
2. R-value reference

### RVO

Take following code as example:

```
struct A {
    int v;
};

A foo(int v) {
    A a;
    a.v = v;
    return a;
}

void bar(A& a, int v) {
    a.v = v;
}

A f;
f = foo(1);

A b;
bar(b, 1);
```

In function `foo`, the variable  `a` is constructed, modify its member `v`, and returns. In an human-optimized version `bar`, `a` is passed in, modified, and gives to caller.

Obviously, `f` and `b` are the same.

And if you know more about C++, you will know in returning from `foo`, result `a` is copied to outer `f`, and the dtor of `a` is called.

The way to make optimized  `foo` into `bar` is called `RVO`, it omits the copy of internal `a` to outer `f`. Modification directly goes to variable of caller.

Please beware, there are cases RVO won't apply: copy ctor has side effect, multiple returns, etc.

Here is a detailed explaination:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[CppWiki](http://www.efnetcpp.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

### RValue

Another way to optimize return value is to use `rvalue ctor` introduced in C++ 11. Generally speaking, it's like calling `std::swap(vector_lhs, vector_rhs)` to swap the internal data pointer to avoid deep copy.

Here is a very good article about optimization:
http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

**Last but not least**

In [Going Native 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Writing-Quick-Code-in-Cpp-Quickly?format=html5), Andrei Alexandrescu gave a talk about how to write quick C++ code. And pass by reference is faster than `rvalue`. (Also RVO has some limitations) So if you do care about performance, please use pass by reference.